# Regression within categorical variable in R

Tags: r, regression

Examining the factors that affect dung beetle abundance, including type of dung  (categorical; 4 species) and the mass of dung (continuous):

```
glm.nb(abundance ~ dung + mass)
```

But how can I test for differences in abundance due to the effect of mass *within* given dung type?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You want to perform a planned contrasts. Make sure this is supported by theory and that you do not run out of degrees of freedom by including too many contrasts.